# How to run a calculation with my query in php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, equation

How do I turn my query into a equation, then print the answer.

**My model**

```
function get_bank()
    {
        $this->db->where('mem_id', $this->session->userdata("id"));
        $query = $this->db->get('bank');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**My view**

```
if (isset($records)) : foreach ($records as $row) : ?>
   $row->i; 
   $row->c; 
   $row->n; 
   $row->p; 
   $row->r;
 endforeach; 
endif;
```

So this is the bit im not sure how to do, run the equation using the data i have from the query

**Equation in view ?**

```
<?php $answer = $i * $n;
print "<h2>$answer</h2>";
;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the values in your loop, why can't you simply write them in a PHP script?

```
<?php
  $x = $row->i / $row->c;
  // and so on...
?>
```

Or if you'd rather:

```
<?php
  $i = $row->i;
  $c = $row->c;

  $x = $i / $c;
  // and so on...
?>
```

Your question wasn't 100% clear to me so if I didn't answer what you were asking, please specify what you're not understanding and I'll make an edit.

Comment: Thank you @ohiodoug just worked it out myself. lol was stupid, i was `$answer = $interest * $start_amount;` instead of `$answer = $row->interest * $row->start_amount;` lol